# GIS SE home page, is the beta jobs link crowding the earlier tabs a known issue?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, user-interface

I just noticed that the `questions` tab is overflowing on to the `GIS` home page title due to the addition of the new `jobs` key. I don't know if it is a glitch SE is already working on or if we need to report it. [image: enter preformatted text here]

Comment: As per the answer, and confirmed by me testing, this appears to have been resolved and so I have set [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a network-wide glitch, which was reported by multiple sites  and quickly fixed.

In the future, I recommend tagging posts about unexpected behavior of the site with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), so that they appear on the developers' bug-monitoring dashboard.